# Query not correct; however, works in MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, pymysql

I am trying to execute a query that selects usernames that are part of user friend groups, people who you follow, and usernames in groups where the user is the groupCreator. I am then trying to count the total reactions for every user across all posts that are part of the selected usernames above for analytics. I know these queries are atrocious to look at, sorry!

My code is giving me this error:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Person JOIN 
Photo ON (Person.username = Photo.poster) JOIN ReactTo USING (pID)WH' at line 1")
```

I don't really understand why I am getting this error when it works in MySQL hardcoded. This is my code. I appreciate the help.

```
def run_sql_many(query, data):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return data
user = session['username']
qAllLikes = 'SELECT firstName, lastName, COUNT(emoji) AS num_reactions' \
            'FROM Person JOIN Photo ON (Person.username = Photo.poster) JOIN ReactTo USING (pID)' \
            'WHERE Person.username IN (' \
            'SELECT DISTINCT username ' \
            'FROM (SELECT username ' \
            'FROM BelongTo ' \
            'WHERE groupName IN (' \
            'SELECT groupName' \
            'FROM BelongTo' \
            'WHERE username = %s)' \
            'OR username IN (' \
            'SELECT username' \
            'FROM BelongTo' \
            'WHERE groupCreator = %s)' \
            ') AS groupUsers' \
            'UNION' \
            '(SELECT username' \
            'FROM Follow JOIN Person ON (Follow.followee = Person.username)' \
            'WHERE follower = %s AND followStatus = 1))' \
            'GROUP BY firstName, lastName'
AllLikes = run_sql_many(qAllLikes, (user, user, user))

return render_template('home.html', username=user, posts=data, postAnalytics=AllLikes)
```

Comment: You need spaces between words at the places where you break your string into lines. You'd be better off using a `'''multi-line string'''`.

Comment: `num_reactions` and `FROM`, and everywhere else

Answer (score 1):

Some whitespaces are missing :

```py
qAllLikes = 'SELECT firstName, lastName, COUNT(emoji) AS num_reactions' \
            'FROM Person JOIN Photo ON (Person.username = Photo.poster) ...'
```

is actually :

```py
qAllLikes = 'SELECT firstName, lastName, COUNT(emoji) AS num_reactionsFROM  Person JOIN Photo ON (Person.username = Photo.poster) ...'
```

So you get `num_reactionsFROM` instead of `num_reactions FROM`

Comment: Ah, I understand. It worked too so thank you! I'm assuming Flask doesn't allow for whitespace whereas SQL does?